# re sizing any image inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've seen quite a few post on here with similar questions and they seemed to have been answered great. However my problem is I can't understand the logic of whats going on and therefore I'm finding looking at the code pointless. Also I really want to be able to understand the code I'm writing. So really I'm not for any complete code as I think I can get that from other posts but if possible could someone explain to me the theory behind the code.

So, if I have a div 500px wide and 400px high and then two photos:

1. photo 1: 1000px wide 800px high
2. photo 2 : 250px wide 700px high

How do I re size these images to fit inside the div without them becoming stretched or distorted.

Like I said in the beginning I'm not looking for code.  Could someone just explain the formula that fits the photos inside the div perfectly.

Comment: Set photo `width` to `100%` in `CSS` - would be a good start.

Comment: Everyone says this, but its not the right answer. Some images are landscape some are portrait, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Why not set it as a background image and use cover?

Answer (score 0):

The (simple) asnwer is that the browser knows the aspect ratio of your image.

If you simply use an `<img>` tag, the image will be displayed in the original size (and aspect ratio).

now, if you specify the width, but not the height, the aspect ration will be kept, so your image will not be distorted.

If you use a CSS attribute like `max-width` and/or `max-height` that is pretty much what happens: your browser takes the image, and if necessary, scales both the with and the height by the same factor to match your specifications.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: What if I have image having height greater that width and I have set width to 100%, in that case how the ratio will be maintained ?

Comment: This is what I mean. There is a formula that people are using that, but I can't make it out completely in their code. So I was hoping some could explain. But these css methods are not the answers, but thanks for your help

Comment: @troybeckett then it seems i did not understand your question correctly. Maybe you could clarify a bit?

Comment: I worked it out myself in the end basically so for anyone interested. To change the size of an image but keep the aspect ratio correct the formulas are:

Answer (score 0):

The browser knows your images aspect ratio. If you want a 250px wide image to fit into a 500px wide container you'll need to scale it and lose quality or keep it as is.

Setting the width to 100% and the height left to auto will scale the image to fit it's width, without assuring that your height will match your desired output. You can scale it based on height, but the same problem applies. This is especially difficult when it comes to making the images responsive.

Using object-fit might help when you're container is the same, but the image vary widely in ratio, as seen here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Or having your images set as a background-image with background-size: cover.